# Reading proper unicode characters into a ReadStream in node.js

Tags: node.js, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, stream

Sometimes strange things happen in the world of coding, and I have no explanation at all. :)

A text file I have contains the following lines:

```
en …π 1 1
en Œ® 1 1
en Œ© 1 1
en –° 1 1
en —† 1 1
en “§ 1 1
en ◊° 2 2
en ·∏§anƒ´f 1 1
en ·π_ 1 1
en ˝mage:whiteshark-tgoss1.jpg 4 4
en ˝stanbul 114 114
```

My code is as follows:

```
var fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName, {encoding: 'utf8'});
fileReadStream.on('data', function(data){
  //do something with the data
});
```

When I look at the data element, all the crazy unicode characters are replaced with �s. ie:

```
en �� 1 1
en �� 1 1
en �� 1 1
en �� 1 1
en �� 1 1
en �� 1 1
en �� 2 2
en ���an��f 1 1
en ��_ 1 1
en �mage:whiteshark-tgoss1.jpg 4 4
en �stanbul 114 114
```

I've tried setting up the ReadStream without the encoding set to UTF8 as well, with no luck.

```
var fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: "when I look at the data element". How are you exactly inspecting data variable?

Comment: Are you sure the file is UTF8?

Comment: there are a few ways that I am checking the data element:
1. Using Console.log
2. The data is being written to couchdb.
3. if I do a (for example) data.search("en ˝stanbul 114 114"); I get no hits, but if I do data.search("en �stanbul 114 114"); it returns a find.

I am not entirely sure it's UTF8, but how would I check? I've opened it up in various editors and all of them default the encoding to UTF8 and display the characters properly! So I'm assuming the file is UTF8. Let me see if I can explicitly convert them to UTF8.

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log(data.toString('hex'))` without passing the encoding parameter? It should be a bunch of lines of hex.

Comment: @loganfsmyth unfortunately the original text files are enourmous (approx. 20,000,000 lines long) and I would have no tools to capture the data. I could try saving them in couch but it would be hard to find the lines in question.

Comment: However, here is some progress, and I think you were onto something about the file encoding: I copied and pasted just the lines with the crazy characters into a new file in a text editor and explicitly encoded the file as UTF-8. The characters read in fine! But this leaves another challenge, which is to determine the original file's encoding. I've tried a bunch of tools to determine that. The tools seem unreliable and inconsistent in their prognosis. But once I know the original charset, I can use iconv to convert the (thousands of) files to UTF8 automatically.

Comment: Okay, can you give me the output of just a couple lines with the special characters then?