# how to use NodeJS to read large utf-8 encoded text file

Tags: node.js, utf-8, text-processing

there are many answers for how to use NodeJS to read utf-8 encoded text file; however, my question is how to read large file. here, the "LARGE" means exceeds memory capability, for example 64GB.

say we have a 64GB JSON file, where the file contains utf-8 characters; how to get the pathKey-value like `locale.ja.test`=`測定`; for example, if we have JSON object like `{ "a": { "b": { "c": 1 } } }`, the value for the pathKey `a.b.c` refers to the value `1`.

if it is ascii encoded text, we can simply split the file into parts; for example, we read file 100MB by 100MB, and use a parser like `parse(previousStat, block) -> stat`; but for utf-8 encoded text, the problem is that, if we split the file into parts, for some corner case, we may split a character into 2 blocks. like `...\0x88\0x12...` -> `[...\x88]`, `[\x12...]`.

how to read large utf-8 encoded text file correctly? Thanks!

notice that: JSON file can be written in one line, which means `readline` may not help.

similar question without answers:

- [Reading proper unicode characters into a ReadStream in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362657/reading-proper-unicode-characters-into-a-readstream-in-node-js)

Comment: Is this a stream of smaller json objects or one large object?

Comment: The multiple objects question has been answered a number of times, a large file not specifically but in either case https://github.com/uhop/stream-json

Comment: utf8 is kind of secondary... all json parsers will support utf8

Comment: @Matt thx for your reply; but it does not work; my question is to read text file, JSON file is just an example; and for `stream-json`, i cannot find how it deal with utf-8 correctly; if we have a JSON file, and some char just hit special control char like`\x88"`; the parser see there is `"` (which will cause problem), but `\x88"` is a utf-8 char ...

Comment: So nodes utf8 encoding on a read stream doesn't work on your file?

Comment: yep, i think i need to get utf-8 chars and also its byte position ... if i use `encoding: utf8` i cannot count byte; if i use raw binary mode, i cannot parse correct utf8 unless i read utf8 standard from scratch ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some trials and errors, i figure out one solution:

for large file, we need to use `stream`: for example, `fs.createReadStream('...')`

for unicode, we need to use a flag `encoding`: `fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file', { encoding: 'utf8', fd: null })`

for counting byte position, we need to convert it to Buffer like `Buffer.from(stream.read()).length`

full example to index a text file in 3-GRAM and 2-GRAM:

This is test -> `[Thi, his, is , s i, is , s t,  te, tes, est]` and `[Th, hi, is, s , i, is, s , t, te, es, st]`

```js
const i_s = require('stream');
const i_fs = require('fs');

function buildIndexer(I) {
   // I = { indexStat: { cur: 0, gram: [] }, index: { gram2: {}, gram3: {} } }
   return i_s.Transform({
      transform: (chunk, _encoding, next) => {
         // _encoding should be 'utf8'
         const N = chunk.length;
         for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            const ch = chunk[i];
            const len = Buffer.from(ch).length;
            I.indexStat.gram.push(ch);
            let gn = I.indexStat.gram.length - 1;
            if (gn > 3) {
               I.indexStat.gram.shift();
               gn --;
            }
            if (gn >= 2) {
               const g2 = `${I.indexStat.gram[gn-2]}${I.indexStat.gram[gn-1]}`;
               I.index.gram2[g2] = I.index.gram2[g2] || [];
               I.index.gram2[g2].push(I.indexStat.cur - Buffer.from(g2).length);
            }
            if (gn >= 3) {
               const g3 = `${I.indexStat.gram[gn-3]}${I.indexStat.gram[gn-2]}${I.indexStat.gram[gn-1]}`;
               I.index.gram3[g3] = I.index.gram3[g3] || [];
               I.index.gram3[g3].push(I.indexStat.cur - Buffer.from(g3).length);
            }
         next(null, chunk);
      },
      decodeStrings: false,
      encoding: 'utf8',
   });
}

const S = i_fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file', { encoding: 'utf8', fd: null });
const I = { indexStat: { cur: 0, gram: [] }, index: { gram2: {}, gram3: {} } }
const T = buildIndexer(I);
S.pipe(T);
S.on('finish', () => S.close());
T.on('finish', () => console.log(I.index));
```